# Can unsafe code in C# cause memory corruption?

Tags: c#, .net

Basically, memory corruption is caused by overwriting memory you're not supposed to overwrite. I am wondering if this is possible with unsafe code in C# (i.e. not by calling into external unmanaged code). I see two possible cases:

- Accessing a null pointer -> Trapped by the CLR, throws a
  NullReferenceException
- Accessing a pointer to an invalid random memory    location ->
  Trapped by the CLR, throws an AccessViolationException

In both cases it seems the runtime detects and prevents the potential memory corruption from taking place. Therefore, is it possible to corrupt memory from C# using unsafe code? And as a corollary, is it safe to catch AccessViolationExceptions from unsafe code?

Comment: In C# it is a NullReferenceExcoption. And I doubt the clr will throw the same exception for managed and unmanaged null dereferences.

Comment: Fixed, thanks. Yes it is the same exception, you easily try it yourself, i.e. `var ptr = (int*)0; *ptr = 1; // throws NullReferenceException`

Comment: Also note that in .net 4.0, by default your process will be terminated if there's indication of corrupted state. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419661.aspx#Four

Comment: thanks for testing.... Learned something today.

Comment: You are missing a third case: accessing a pointer to a valid memory location that contains data that must not be modified by you. Not trapped by the CLR, no exception, corrupts memory.

Comment: More generally: the "unsafe code" feature was called "unsafe" because **it is not safe**.  The CLR does not guarantee to save you from your mistakes; that's why it's called "unsafe".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Accessing a pointer to an invalid random memory location

If it is a read, it is safe. If it was a write it is unsafe if the memory location happened to be valid, but you did not own it. You'll be scribbling over random memory locations.

> And as a corollary, is it safe to catch AccessViolationExceptions from unsafe code?

No, because that exception tells you a) that you have a bug and b) that memory might be corrupted which cannot be repaired. Catch it and tear down the process asap.

Comment: " If it was a write it is unsafe if the memory location happened to be valid, but you did not own it." If it's outside your application's boundaries, Windows will kill your process, AFAIK.

Comment: @Renan if you did not handle the exception, yes.

Comment: I don't quite understand why memory could be corrupted if an AccessViolationException is thrown. Doesn't the fact that it's thrown imply that the CLR has trapped the attempt to access invalid memory, and hence did not allow it to happen?

Comment: The exception might be thrown after a silent corruption has occurred. Also, if you wrote across page boundaries you might have produce a half-written write.

Comment: A write could corrupt things even if you do own the memory location. Unsafe code could scribble over the top of a managed object, heap data structures, stack frames, etc.

Comment: @JimMischel you do not own object headers or stacks.

Comment: Ahhhh ... so it depends on what we mean by "own." But, okay. I see your point.

Answer (score 13):

You are missing the Big Bullet:

- accessing memory and **not** getting an AccessViolationException.

Which is *very* common, there's always lots of writable memory around in a .NET program.  Including writing the element beyond the end of an array, it rarely bombs.  Memory protection is granular at memory page boundaries, 4096 bytes on Windows.  The .NET GC bumps that up considerably, the generational heap segments are nice big hunks of VM.   Catching AVEs is very unwise.

Some code to play with:

```
class Program {
    static unsafe void Main(string[] args) {
        var arr = new byte[1];
        for (int fill = 0; fill < 2 * 1024 - 64; ++fill) {
            byte[] dummy = new byte[1024];
        }
        fixed (byte* p = &arr[0]) {
            for (int ix = 1; ; ++ix)
                p[ix] = 42;
        }
    }
}
```

Overshoots by about 1.5 megabytes.

Answer (score 7):

> Can unsafe code in C# cause memory corruption?

Answer is yes!, Consider the following example does that

```
int a = 10;
int* p = &a;
*(p+54)= 444;
```

CLR may or may not trap this.

> Not all reads or writes through bad pointers lead to access violations, so an access violation usually indicates that several reads or writes have occurred through bad pointers, and that memory might be corrupted.

From [Accessviolationexception Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.accessviolationexception.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The memory write that caused the AccessViolationException did not happen, it does not do anything.

However: The fact that it tried to write to a wrong location is a very strong indicator that there might have been invalid write operations before (since your code is buggy), and those writes could have been pointing to locations that are writable but were not supposed to be changed.